# How does browser fix broken HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html-parsing

Try following in browser console:

```
a = document.createElement('div')

a.innerHTML = '<p><footer></footer>'
a // <div><p></p><footer></footer></div>

a.innerHTML = '<div><footer></footer>'
a // <div><div><footer></footer></div></div>
```

It fixes as `<p></p><footer></footer>` for broken `<p>` while it does as `<div><footer></footer></div>` for broken `<div>`.

Is there any standard? Or is this decided by browser?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing). Short answer is, yes, there is a standard.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, I will take a deep look.

Comment: In both cases, the elements get closed when they _have to_ be closed. You realize the fundamental difference between the two given examples, right? `div` may contain `footer`, so that can be closed “at the end”, whereas `p` may _not_ contain `footer`, so it gets closed _before_ that element. And not all those “left out” tags are actually _errors_, btw. – https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: Can someone help with the algorithm used for fixing broken html ?